# First Posts Problems

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently I've noticed that most first posts/late answers are way off-topic. A lot of new users don't know the rules and ask for lists, equipment recommendation etc.

I guess that people don't really read the about section. So, I wanted to suggest something:

When a new user tries to post something new for 3-4 times, a small box will appear next/under/above the box he is writing his post that will consist of 3 lines,just with the very basics of the site's rules.

Like:

> Please note that in our site, it is not on-topic to:
>
> - ask for lists
> - ask for equipment recommendation
> - ask for analysis of a specific song etc

Comment: I think there is an equivalent question on meta.so - I'll try and link to it.